# Putting the end results in a Map efficiently

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am getting the result of the query into a list which I want to put into the map, actually, I have a query which selects the records from the table of two columns based on the input conditions   passed and fetches the result into the list

Now I want to change the concept as I want to store the results of two columns into the map,    for example, first value abcId would be the key and the second value pack would be the value of that key in a map. Later I would change the return type of that map also so please advise how can I place it on the map?

```
@Transactional
    public List<CTM> fetchAllCTMinfo(String avJobCode){
        TypedQuery<CTM> typedQuery = em.createQuery("SELECT i.abcId , i.pAcq FROM CTM i where i.avJobCode = :avJobCode", CTM.class);
        typedQuery.setParameter("avJobCode", avJobCode);
        Map<Integer, String> hm = new HashMap< Integer , String>
        List<CTM> list = typedQuery.getResultList(); 
        if(list != null && list.size()>0)
        {
        return list;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

so the resulting map should be like

```
abcId   |  pAcq
10          fgtr
20          fgrt
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate the list and put it into the map

```
HashMap<Integer, String> hm = new HashMap<Integer , String>
List<CTM> list = fetchAllCTMinfo(String avJobCode);
for (CTM ctm : list) {
    hm.put(ctm.getId(), ctm.getString());
}
```

Replace `getId()` and `getString()` methods according to your `CTM` class.